# how in singleton instance call interface

Tags: java, android

This is my class

```
public class MyReceiver implements TolEnabled
```

and here i want to call

```
MyManager.getInstance(context, this, Properties.SDSMT, localText.toString(), Integer.valueOf(repetitions), false);
```

and in `MyManager` class I have singleton like

```
public static MyManager getInstance(Context context, TolEnabled tolActivitiy, String enginePackage, String text, int repetition) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new MyManager (...);
        }

        return instance;
    }
```

but in my `MyReceiver` receiver when i call singleton i get

> The method getInstance(Context, TolEnabled, String, String, int) in
>   the type MyReceiver is not applicable for the arguments (Context,
>   MyReceiver , String, String, Integer, boolean)

what can i do? `MyReceiver` implements interface and works if is not singleton. How to use it in singleton?

Comment: Just an advice: Be careful with singletons in Android. If they are stateful you can get unexpected results if the singleton survices an aparently closed application. This will happen, if the OS does not terminate the jvm running your application. If you restart your application you will get the same jvm and the "old" singleton instance (and the old state).

Comment: so you suggest to remove singleton? I want to use it because i need some method many times and in the same instance. And static method i think is worse then singleton. Is this correct?

Comment: You are right wrt. to static methods if you need to pass lots of cpntext information into the statis method which would be available to a non-static method. You could use the Application object instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is declared as follow

```
Context, TolEnabled, String, String, int
```

And when you call getInstance, you provide the following arguments

```
Context, MyReceiver , String, String, Integer, boolean
```

Conclusion: remove the last boolean parameter.

Comment: thank you my mistake, how i did not see that :(

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of things you're providing an additional boolean parameter in your call to getInstance which isn't expected by the getInstance signature.

Comment: thank you my mistake, how i did not see that :(

Comment: No probs!  Please mark any of these answers as accepted if we've helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You either need to remove the boolean condition in

```
MyManager.getInstance(context, this, Properties.SDSMT, localText.toString(), Integer.valueOf(repetitions), false);
```

Or modifiy the `MyManager.getInstance()` method to accept a boolean as the last parameter.

```
public static MyManager getInstance(Context context, TolEnabled tolActivitiy, String enginePackage, String text, int repetition, boolean condition) {
  if (instance == null) {
            instance = new MyManager (...);
        }

        return instance;
}
```

Comment: thank you my mistake, how i did not see that :(

Comment: @mbrc youll need to accept one of the answers as the correct one. by clicking on the clear tick mark underneath the various answers